# Tagging files, not just images

Tags: sound, files, tagging

How can I tag files in Ubuntu?

I know how to tag images with shotwell, but I want to tag all files (text, audio, ...) not just images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out [Tracker Tags](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/tracker-tag.1.html). It's been pretty legit for my purposes

Maybe some more info on the [Meta Tracker Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaTracker)?

Comment: Support for MetaTracker seems not very well. Wiki page is outdated (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaTracker) but nevertheless thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extended attributes.
You need the *attr* package.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install attr
```

Creating a tag:

```
setfattr -n user.foo -v bar yourfile
```

Listing tags on a file:

```
getattr -d yourfile
```

For GUI, you can use Eiciel

You can add Eiciel to Nautilus and Thunar using custom actions.

For searching, you can use *Recoll*

Here is a good read:
https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/pages/extattrs.html